# What are the default tcp ports used by GridGain

Tags: docker, gridgain

I would like to run GridGain from within a Docker container.

What are the default TCP ports used by GridGain that are required to be exposed by the Docker container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start GridGain from command line with `ggstart.sh -v` option (verbose mode), the used ports will be printed out.